# Facebook App re-submission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-ads-api, facebook-app-settings

I'm trying to resubmit app for review, because Facebook couldn't find the Facebook Login button in app.

The permissions I request are as follows:

Do you have any idea where can upload screencast??

[image]

Comment: Oh for ... sake, just click “Edit Details” and see what happens …

Comment: @CBroe i have clicked but there only can write detailed step-by-step instructions not to upload video...

Comment: Which one of the two items on that above list are you talking about?

Comment: @CBroe for first item https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZla1.png

Comment: Well if it doesn’t _ask_ for a screencast there, then that likely means none is required regarding that specific part of the functionality either.

Comment: Plus, that item is already marked green, so it seems you got it reviewed already (should show up in the approved items list further down the page, no?) … in which case, why would you want to submit it again?

Comment: @CBroe In list down the page there are only approved default permissions... When submit the app for review, they cannot find "Continue with facebook", so i think maybe need to upload screencast...Want to resubmit for App Verification marked with red..

Comment: You can’t upload a screencast in places that don’t ask for any. Either write better step-by-step instructions, explaining where to go to login - or put the URL to your screencast uploaded somewhere externally (youtube, dropbox, whatever) in there.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you .. write this comment in answer section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t upload a screencast in places that don’t ask for any.

Try and write better step-by-step instructions, explaining where to go to login - and/or put the URL to your screencast uploaded somewhere externally (youtube, dropbox, whatever) in there.